# Is my FX brokerage manipulating my profit margin to pay out less?

Tags: foreign-exchange, brokerage, usd-us-dollar, margin

[USDCAD pair has moved 41.90 pips in my favour @ 0.01 lots (broker showing profit of $3.01)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K86bQ.png)

[USDJPY pair has moved 52.30 pips against me @ 0.01 lots (broker showing loss of -$4.85)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgfse.png)

At $0.10 per pip (0.01 lot) the margin on:

- USDCAD pair is (41.90 pips * $0.10 - $3.01 listed profit = 1.18) while
- USDJPY pair is (52.30 pips * $0.10 - $4.84 listed loss = 0.39)

It seems my profit margins are calculated at a higher "spread" than my loss? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are comparing CAD with JPY and you need to factor in the exchange rate differential bwteen the two

Answer (score 0):

AH, one reason is that "open profit" is calculated on liquidation value, NOT on current price. At best with a market having bid and ask, it is using the worse of those numbers.